# duplex affecting bandwidth test, router--switch--NIC

Tags: networking

Netgear FVS336gv3 router, 50x50 dedicated fiber.

ISP instructed us to set WAN port speed to 100mbps full duplex; done.
Router connected to Netgear GS748T 48-port switch.

GS748T port set to "auto" which docs says actually means 1000mbps, full duplex. 
NIC in laptop set to auto negotiate.

speedtest is 50x25. 
set NIC in laptop to 100mbps full duplex, speedtest is 50x50.

what is going on here?

Can only achieve full bandwidth speed test when the laptop NIC is defined at 100mbps full. I tested 1000mbps full on the laptop NIC and speedtest is 50x25.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way ethernet negotiates speed and duplex.

When both sides are set to Auto, the speed and duplex will be negotiated to the best possible speed and duplex, giving you the best throughput.

When you specifically set the speed on one side, negotiation doesn't happen. If the other side is set to Auto, it can detect, not negotiate, the link speed. The problem happens with duplex. Since negotiation is disabled, the side set to Auto just uses the default duplex for the particular speed it detects. That is Half Duplex for 10 and 100 Mbps, and Full Duplex for 1000 Mbps.

That means that your host is set to 100 Mbps, Full Duplex, but your switch port, set to Auto, will configure itself to use 100 Mbps, Half Duplex. Mismatched duplex will cause you no end of problems. If you can look at the errors on the switch port, you will see a bunch of different errors, including collisions and runts. You throughput will suffer greatly.

For the best possible speed and duplex, you should set both sides to Auto, or both sides to the exact same speed and duplex, and anyone who tells you different doesn't really understand how it works.

Comment: on router, I set the speed/duplex under the WAN setup section; thinking it would only effect the WAN port. I'm assuming all 4 LAN ports on the router are always AUTO. Setting switches to 100 mbps full duplex to match the WAN setting would waste internal LAN bandwidth; all equipment is gigabit. Please advise.